# ES6 template literals inside jQuery $.each method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

Is it possible to use ES6 template literals inside jQuery's `$.each` method?

Tried to do like this, without success:

```
let arr = this.arr;

  $.each($("g#texts").children(), function (i, contents) {
    $("#`${contents.id}` tspan")
        .text(arr.find(a => a.name == "`${contents.id}`")
        .displayedName);
  })
```

What should be corrected here?

Comment: Those are not ES6 template literals. That's template syntax inside a string literal.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's certainly possible. The issue you have is because you've placed the template literal inside a string literal. The second template literal is also redundant. If you fix the syntax the code you have written will work fine:

```js
$("g#texts").children().each(function (i, contents) {
  $(`#${contents.id} tspan`).text(arr.find(a => a.name == contents.id).displayedName);
});
```

Comment: jQuery gives me an error on this: "Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: # tspan ...". The "tspan" is nested inside a "text" element (SVG). Setting new text values works fine when hardcoding; ${} literals won't cooperate though.

Comment: The error implies that the Element that `contents` is pointing to has no `id` attribute, hence the invalid selector `# tspan` is being used

Comment: That's the point: I didn't set ids of all children and the method went on empty values. Now I got this corrected and everything works perfectly, thank you for helping!